# Finding percentage of value of a particular record with respect to the entire result

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Below query example shows the actual result of what I want my query to fetch. I was wondering if there was any better/efficient way of writing it:

```
with x as
(select 'A' institution, 100 value_x, 40 value_y from dual union all
select 'B' institution, 200 value_x, 70 value_y from dual union all
select 'C' institution, 10 value_x, 95 value_y from dual)
select 
institution,
case when sum(value_x) over (partition by null) != 0 then round((value_x/sum(value_x) over (partition by null))*100,2) else 0 end value_x_percent,
case when sum(value_y) over (partition by null) != 0 then round((value_y/sum(value_y) over (partition by null))*100,2) else 0 end value_y_percent
from x
```

Any advice/suggestion is welcome, however please explain why your query is better than what I am doing. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer `NULL` to `0` for the case when the denominator is zero.  So, I would be inclined to use:

```
with x as (
      select 'A' institution, 100 value_x, 40 value_y from dual union all
      select 'B' institution, 200 value_x, 70 value_y from dual union all
      select 'C' institution, 10 value_x, 95 value_y from dual
    )
select institution,
       round((value_x / nullif(sum(value_x) over (), 0) * 100, 2) as value_x_percent,
       round((value_y / nullif(sum(value_y) over (), 0)) * 100, 2)  value_y_percent
from x;
```

You can use `coalesce()` to get `0` back.

As for performance, this should be fine.  I doubt any other method would have better performance.  And the code is already pretty concise.

Answer (score 2):

You may try `RATIO_TO_REPORT` function  :[**docs**](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions124.htm)

```
with x as
(select 'A' institution, 100 value_x, 40 value_y from dual union all
select 'B' institution, 200 value_x, 70 value_y from dual union all
select 'C' institution, 10 value_x, 95 value_y from dual)
SELECT institution
    , ROUND ( 100 * (RATIO_TO_REPORT(value_x) OVER ()), 2) AS value_x_percent
    , ROUND ( 100 * (RATIO_TO_REPORT(value_y) OVER ()), 2) AS value_y_percent
FROM x;
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e0ee9e/580)

Comment: Can you advise why it is better than my logic ?, Does `sum(value_y) over (partition by null)` have any downside in any scenario ?

Comment: @pOrinG : Your logic has `partition by null`, which is redundant . sum() over() works for most dbs, but `RATIO_TO_REPORT` is an analytical function optimized to compute the ratio of a value to the sum of a set of values.It is specific to Oracle. I recommend you to go for it , though i don't have the performance benchmark for the two right now.

Comment: Thank you for the answer & comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with x as
(select 'A' institution, 100 value_x, 40 value_y   union all
select 'B' institution, 200 value_x, 70  union all
select 'C' institution, 10 value_x, 95 value_y  ) 

select *,  value_x/cast((select sum(value_x) from x) as float) x_percentofwhole,
 value_y/cast((select sum(value_y) from x) as float) y_percentofwhole from x
```